# Android Phone (HTC ADR6300VW) freezes but doesn't crash, logcat doesn't print stack trace

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Android freezes right when it is supposed to crash and the app becomes completely nonresponsive. The Eclipse Logcat doesn't show any errors or print the stack trace, though it does show system and warning outputs. I tested other apps and they crash and print their stack trace in the logcat. This happens in multiple different places in the app where it should crash. The debugger attaches successfully.

I am using async tasks for networking and backend work but the errors that cause crashing happen on the main thread.

**Update1** The app crashes properly and logcat prints a stack trace when running on an emulator. Resetting ADB from console does not solve problem, though it does recognize that adb is attached to the device. Unchecking and then re-checking "Android debugging" does not solve problem. I'm guessing the problem lies with the phone?

**Update2** Factory resetting the phone didn't solve it.

**Update3** I tested on another Android phone, a Galaxy S4, and it crashed and printed a stack trace properly. The problem device is a HTC ADR6300VW running Gingerbread (API 10).

Comment: If you attach the debugger to your program while it's frozen, what is it doing?

Comment: It's hard to help you with this kind of description, but you can first check if you are using AsyncTasks, sometimes the use of AsyncTasks to execute multy tasks can generate some strange behaviours because of the one task per time rule

Comment: It is possible that your app crashes in emulator because of OOM at some place where it is doing some time and memory consuming task (may be in loop). To be sure try to rum your app on a low configuration device As in devices having more memory and good processor this will surely throw an ANR.

Comment: I've ruled OOM out--I deliberately call a method on a null object in my starting activity's onCreate() so that I can see whether the stack trace shows up in the logcat. Also, the app doesn't give an ANR screen / interface, it just jams up right where it should crash and forcibly close itself.